# Determine if process was launched directly from a terminal window or programmatically as a child process

Tags: bash, shell, tty

If a user runs a process from a terminal, is it possible to tell?
Compared to if the process was launch from a program, where that program was launched from a terminal.

The use case is if it's run by the terminal, it will look like this:

```
suman:
suman:
suman:
```

but if it's run by another program x, it could look like this, if x prepends something to stdout/stderr:

```
x: suman:
x: suman:
```

but I want to detect that, so it just looks like:

```
x:
x:    
x:
```

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Comment: Running a process that way *is* running it from a program.  There isn't some magic distinction, and "run from a terminal" is an erroneous concept that is a fundamental flaw in this question.  All programs are run by other programs.  Terminals are not programs.  They are *devices* that a program that runs programs can potentially be talking to.  (They are devices with a program at the other end, be it one running in ROM on a piece of physical hardware or a software emulator running locally.  But that does not make the terminal device the thing that runs stuff.)  Shells are programs.

Comment: I will add the use case to the OP

Comment: @JdeBP I understand that :) Let's ditch the semantics - does the question make sense to you or not? The question is - did the user launch the program by typing it into a terminal and hitting enter, or did a program launch it? It doesn't have to be exact, a best guess will do, in terms of whether it knows how it was launched (by a human or machine).

Comment: Then why base a question on such a faulty premise?  And what on earth is the antecedent for "it".  *What* will look like that?  Why do you think that it will in fact look like that in the first place?  And "typing it into a terminal and hitting enter" *causes* a program to launch it.  You apparently do not understand this well enough.

Comment: It's not a faulty premise dogg, @Peschke's answer is on the right track follow that lead

Comment: As stated it's a guessing game, you can't know for sure

Comment: If the program X is known and fixed, you can look for the parent process ID (or the whole chain) as described in the answer, and see if X is in this chain. This is well-defined, and no guessing game. The general case is difficult if you can't specify e.g. what kind of terminal etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can see what the parent process ID (PPID) is of the process in question, then use the PPID to determine if it was ran from a shell or different program.

For example, if I wanted to see what was running this `sleep` process, I can look for it's PPID.

```
$ ps -ef | grep "sleep"
user       2470  1996  0 06:30 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 60
```

PID 1996 is the PPID of the `sleep` process. Let's `grep` for that now.

```
$ ps -ef | grep 1996
user       1996  1995  0 05:57 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
```

PID 1996 is a `bash` shell, which is a good indication that the `sleep` process *could be* running from a terminal. To take it even one step further, you can `grep` for the PPID of the `bash` process.

```
$ ps -ef | grep 1995
user       1995   448  0 05:57 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/bin/urxvt
```

The PPID of the `bash` process is `urxvt`, a virtual terminal. So the `sleep` command is being ran from a terminal.

Comment: interesting something like this might work

Comment: How can you tell from that that the `bash` shell is interactive or a script?

Comment: @Kusalananda: I think it's a guessing game. The arguments for the process shown in `ps` could be a hint. For example, `urxvt` vs `urxvt -e`. Another hint could be if the processes originate from a `tty` vs `pts`. However, someone could be executing commands via an `expect` script over `ssh` for all we know.

Comment: It's worse than a guessing game.  It's conceptually faulty.  Run a subordinate interactive shell in the login session, and suddenly *every* (non-built-in) command run is in the second category given by the question.

Comment: @JdeBP it's NOT a faulty question. Did a human hit enter to launch the program or not? Last time I checked, Linux doesn't give you a way to know that. Doesn't meant it's a faulty question, it's only that Linux never offered a way to know if a program was "launched by a human".

Comment: @AlexanderMills: Not only that, but my understanding is that operating systems *can't* determine if a process was launched by a human or not. Many programs exist that simulate human interactions.

Comment: Not only does the question *not say that* (Why are you writing this so badly?), the fundamental flaw of the question and answer is further compounded by the notion of, say, simply shelling out from `vi` or `mailx`.  Or running things like `mysql` or an orthodox file manager.  Or `script`.

Answer (score 0):

When you source the script running with . or source before, the command **ps** will NOT list the sourced script name. So, one way is to do a grep to check if the sourced script name is in the ps output, indicating that it was NOT sourced.

Example: lets supose that a file "myscript" has this coommand:

```
cd /run/user/1000  #it will only affect terminal pwd if is sourced!
```

If you run directly:

```
$ myscript  # ps will contain 'myscript' in the list.
# The cd command will not change the terminal current directory (pwd)
```

Otherwise if you use 'source' or a dot (.) before:

```
$ . myscript       # ps will not list "myscript" as it was sourced
$ source myscript  # source works the same as .
# Your terminal pwd will change to /run/user/1000
```

Changing 'myscript' to be effective:

```
ck=`ps | grep -o -m 3 -E 'myscript'`

cd /run/user/1000

if [ -n "$ck" ]; then # -n means "not empty"
  printf "\E[07;91mYou must source the script, run . myscript\E[0m\n"
  exit
fi

# or negative logic ... 

if [ -z "$ck" ]; then  # -z means null, empty
  echo "You are runnig the sourced script, now run pwd to check it"
fi
```